# Direct link to tabItem with R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using the shiny dashboard template to generate my web UI.

I'd like to dynamically generate an infobox when a computation is completed with a link directed to one of the tabItems in `dashboardBody`.

For example,
I can put this in my `tabItem1` output,

```
renderInfoBox({
  infoBox("Completed", 
    a("Computation Completed", href="#tabItem2"), 
  icon = icon("thumbs-o-up"), color = "green"
  )
})
```

But the problem is that when I click the link, it does nothing. I would like it jumps to `tabItem2`. The link href seems valid when I hover on it.

Thanks!

---

Update:
Other than using Javascripts, looks like using `actionLink` and `updateTabItems` functions in `shinydashboard` package will work as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I apologize for the lengthy code sample, but I had to copy an example with `tabItems` from the shinydashboard homepage.

Your approach has only few problems. First, if you would inspect the `menuItems`, you'd see that the actual tab's id is not `tabItem2`, but `shiny-tab-tabItem2`. This, plus the extra attribute `data-toggle="tab"` within the `a` tag would suffice to open the desired tab. Snippet:

```
a("Computation Completed", href="#shiny-tab-tabItem2", "data-toggle" = "tab")
```

But, this has its limits. First and most obvious, the state of the `menuItem` in the sidebar is not set to `active`. This looks very odd and one might not be convinced, that one has been moved to another tab.

Second, and less obvious, if you listen to tab changes (on the server side), you will not get information about this tab switch. Those are triggered by the `menuItem` being clicked, and the tab itself will not report if it is visible or hidden.

So, my approach will be to simulate that the corresponding `menuItem` is clicked, and thus, all the above problems are solved.

Code example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Some Header"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Computations", tabName = "tabItem1", icon = icon("dashboard")),
        menuItem("Results", tabName = "tabItem2", icon = icon("th"))
      )
    ),

    dashboardBody(
      tags$script(HTML("
        var openTab = function(tabName){
          $('a', $('.sidebar')).each(function() {
            if(this.getAttribute('data-value') == tabName) {
              this.click()
            };
          });
        }
      ")),
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "tabItem1",
          fluidRow(
            box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

            box(
              title = "Controls",
              sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
            )
          ),
          infoBoxOutput("out1")
        ),

        tabItem(tabName = "tabItem2",
          h2("Widgets tab content")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })

  output$out1 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("Completed",  
      a("Computation Completed", onclick = "openTab('tabItem2')", href="#"),
      icon = icon("thumbs-o-up"), color = "green"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note, that the only important thing is the `onclick` property, not an `href`. This means, that every `div` or other element can be used to create this link. You could even have just the thumbs-up image with this `onclick` command.

If you have more questions, please comment.

Best Regards

---

**Edit: Whole infoBox clickable.**

This is an answer to a comment by *OmaymaS*. The point was to make the infoBox a clickable container. To achieve this, one can define a new function that makes a somewhat different infoBox. The custom box will be as follows:

```
customInfoBox <- function (title, tab = NULL, value = NULL, subtitle = NULL, icon = shiny::icon("bar-chart"), color = "aqua", width = 4, href = NULL, fill = FALSE) {
    validateColor(color)
    tagAssert(icon, type = "i")
    colorClass <- paste0("bg-", color)
    boxContent <- div(class = "info-box", class = if (fill) colorClass, 
        onclick = if(!is.null(tab)) paste0("$('.sidebar a')).filter(function() { return ($(this).attr('data-value') == ", tab, ")}).click()"),
        span(class = "info-box-icon", class = if (!fill) colorClass, icon),  
        div(class = "info-box-content", 
            span(class = "info-box-text", title), 
            if (!is.null(value)) span(class = "info-box-number", value), 
            if (!is.null(subtitle)) p(subtitle)
        )
    )
    if (!is.null(href)) boxContent <- a(href = href, boxContent)
    div(class = if (!is.null(width)) paste0("col-sm-", width), boxContent)
}
```

This code is copied from the original `infoBox` function definition and only the line with `onclick` is new. I also added the `openTab` function (with some twitches) right inside the container such that you dont need to worry where to put this function inside the view. Might be a bit overloaded i feel. 
This custom info box can be used exactly like the default one and if you pass the additional `tab` argument, the link to the sidebar is added.

---

**Edit: Subtitle exploit**

As *Alex Dometrius* mentioned, the use of `subtitle` crashes this functionality. This is because the script tag that was inserted, on accident, was used as the `subtitle` argument in order to be rendered with the box. To free up this spot, I edited the main example up top such that the script tag is sitting top level in the `dashboardBody` (literally anywhere in the ui would be fine).

(To avoid confusion: in Version 1, the `tags$script` was supplied inside of `infobox` where it was interpreted as the `subtitle` parameter.)

Comment: That is very neat! I really appreciate it.

Comment: What if I want to apply it to the whole infobox, i.e. any part of the infobox. I am not sure what is the tag, tried to checkout but didn't work. any clue?

Comment: @OmaymaS I believe (without having tried it) you could just move the `onclick` property from the `a`-tag one line up to the `infoBox` tag. This should add the functionality to the whole infobox container.

Comment: @K.Rohde if you mean sth like infoBox(onclick = "openTab('trigram_model')", ), it does not work.

Comment: @OmaymaS I see. But from looks of it, the `infoBox` function is not that complicated. So you might even rewrite it and use kind of a customized version. Sadly this comment box is too small for a full code sample...

Comment: @OmaymaS Edited the answer. I did not test this but it should work.

Comment: For some reason I cannot get this to work for me (the first answer). A new tab opens but I get a "Not Found" error. It looks like there is a lot of white space in the URI when the tab opens even though I have tried to remove it all. Would this have anything to do with having separate ui.R and server.R files for my app?

Comment: @AlexDometrius Separating the files should be no problem and also "Not Found" can also not really happen here. Could you create a new question with your actual code and reference it here?

Comment: In the process of creating a reprex it seems to work. But when plugged into a much larger/more complex app it fails even when the logic seems to be exactly the same. I removed all of the white space and I now get the following URI:

    http://127.0.0.1:3306/<script>var openTab = function(tabName){$('a', $('.sidebar')).each(function(){if(this.getAttribute('data-value') == tabName){this.click()};});}</script>

Comment: @K.Rohde , I also tried your second example and I am getting: Error: could not find function "validateColor". Thanks for the help. Not sure if this is a version issue or what I am experiencing.

Comment: @K.Rohde , Looks like it does not work if you specify a subtitle in the infoBox. Removing that makes it work. But I would like to keep my subtitle if possible.

Comment: @AlexDometrius Thanks for this finding. I updated the answer to correct the issue with subtitle. Hopefully, this addresses the other errors you were experiencing.

Comment: @K.Rohde . That did it. +1. What about changing the pointer to actually help the user better understand that the text is clickable? Currently it is still showing the I-beam cursor.

Comment: @AlexDometrius Try adding `href="#"` as an additional parameter to the `a` tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176254/discussion-between-alex-dometrius-and-k-rohde).

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with a simple text hyperlink? If I implement ```a("Computation Completed", href="#shiny-tab-tabItem2", "data-toggle" = "tab") ``` , I can add a link inside a paragraph, p(), of text, but get the behavior you describe above where it is not clear that I have switched tabs.

Comment: The process described in the Answer only works because we are manipulating the Bootstap.js components, which are used to render the visibility of the tabs. By simulating a "click" on the actual tab field, the logic from this JavaScript library is executed. Your hyperlink will not do that by default just because Bootstrap is not implemented in this way. The only way (which is not better than the original answer) is to globally listen to clicks with #-hrefs and trigger those fake tab clicks.